# Doctrine ManyToOne onDelete SetNull

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 2 tables one is product, a product can only have one brand ofc but there's multiple products that can have the same brand.

I try to set onDelete="Null" on the brand_id field of Product when I delete the brand, but it doesn't work :S

Here's product

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $brand;
```

here's brand

```
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="brand")
     * 
     */
    private $productTypes;
```

this is what i get from my dump-sql :

```
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_29D6873E84D1E8E7 ON offer (product_cat_id);
     ALTER TABLE sym_order DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_B88A9287E7A1254A;
     ALTER TABLE sym_order ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B88A9287E7A1254A FOREIGN KEY (contact_id) REFERENCES sym_contact (id);
     ALTER TABLE sym_product_type DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_5052FAC44F5D008;
     ALTER TABLE sym_product_type DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_5052FAC44F5D008;
     ALTER TABLE sym_product_type ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5052FAC44F5D008 FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
     DROP INDEX uniq_5052fac44f5d008 ON sym_product_type;
     CREATE INDEX IDX_5052FAC44F5D008 ON sym_product_type (brand_id);
     ALTER TABLE sym_product_type ADD CONSTRAINT FK_5052FAC44F5D008 FOREIGN KEY (brand_id) REFERENCES brand (id);
     ALTER TABLE sym_stock DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_695577F14959723;
     ALTER TABLE sym_stock CHANGE status status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL;
     ALTER TABLE sym_stock ADD CONSTRAINT FK_695577F14959723 FOREIGN KEY (product_type_id) REFERENCES sym_product_type (id) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Note also that I have an error when I try to update --force but I suppose it still execute the rest right ?

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: I believe the default for any `JoinColumn` is `nullable=false`, so to set it to null (onDelete or otherwise), it should be nullable. Besides that, you *surely* get an error message. Why don't you add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If error occurs while executing

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Execution stop on last successful command. That is probably your problem because annotations seems defined correctly.

You can check unexecuted commands with:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

If every SQL command is executed correctly, this command inform you that your schema is up to date.

Comment: thanks for your answer it was that. I had duplicates in DB because of a UNIQ Key, I modified the relation of those tables to ManyToOne, then I did an update --force, it solved the situation